# I have an editor mask in flash that displays it's movement without hitting enter key

Tags: flash-cs4

I made a circular mask in 3dsMax, imported into flash as an swf, used it to mask a movieclip. The thing is that when i drag the movieclip to the stage, the mask animates without hitting enter key consuming a lot of ide resources, anyone has an idea of why is this happening? Using Flash CS4

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Flash CS5 it works perfectly. Anyway we found the solution, the mask was a movieclip, we selected all the frames and converted to a symbol and it works!